# Semiample line bundle and tensor product

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a projective variety over a field $k$ of characteristic $0$. Let $L$ and $M$ be semiample line bundles, i.e. some tensor power $L^{\otimes p}$ and $M^{\otimes q}$ are globally generated. Can we prove that $L\otimes M$ is semiample? If not, is there any good counter-example of this?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

If $L^{\otimes p}$ is globally generated then $L^{\otimes pq} \cong (L^{\otimes p})^{\otimes q}$ is globally generated as well. Similarly, $M^{\otimes pq}$ is globally generated. Finally,
$$
(L \otimes M)^{\otimes pq} \cong 
L^{\otimes pq} \otimes M^{\otimes pq}
$$
is also globally generated.